# Need explaining on the double label function declaration

Tags: swift

I was reading the apple doc when I fell upon this piece of syntax :

```
struct Point {
    var x = 0.0, y = 0.0
    mutating func moveBy(x deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double) {
        x += deltaX
        y += deltaY
    }
}
var somePoint = Point(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
somePoint.moveBy(x: 2.0, y: 3.0)
print("The point is now at (\(somePoint.x), \(somePoint.y))")
// Prints "The point is now at (3.0, 4.0)"
```

Could someone explain why `moveBy(x deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double)` has double labels on the arguments ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: first argument label is for external caller, second one for local in-method use.

`func moveBy(x deltaX: Double, y deltaY: Double)` when calling looks following: `moveBy(x: 1, y: 1)`, but inside the method `deltaX` and `deltaY` labels are used.

This naming style is not necessary, you can declare the method `func moveBy(x: Double, y: Double)` so `x` and `y` will be used inside the method.

To support legacy style, so from caller scope your method looks like `moveBy(1, 1)`, you should place `_` as first argument label: `func moveBy(_ deltaX: Double, _ deltaY: Double)`. Such declarations are used in CocoaTouch to support legacy obj-c interface (ex. `func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool`).

Answer (score 2):

The *first* label is ***Argument Labels*** and the *second* label is ***Parameter Names***.

**From Apple Document**:

> Each function parameter has both an argument label and a parameter
>   name. The argument label is used when calling the function; each
>   argument is written in the function call with its argument label
>   before it. The parameter name is used in the implementation of the
>   function. By default, parameters use their parameter name as their
>   argument label.

**Usage**:

```
func foo(with hoge: Int) {
    return hoge * 2
}


let A = foo(with: 2) // A = 4;
```

Answer (score 1):

Look closely to the Apple [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID351).It is connected with **Parameter Names**.

> You can override the default behavior for argument labels with one of
>   the following forms:

**argument label parameter name: parameter type**

**_ parameter name: parameter type**